# how can i use openlayers to use my locally rendered tiles

Tags: openlayers-2, mapnik

I've been stuck on how to use my local tiles which i rendered with mapnik's generate_tiles.py and all the data is on postgresql. I'm kinda confused on what i should do to "feed" the tiles to openlayers. The map would be used in django btw. hoping you could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on Windows, I have simple duplicated the call of Openstreetmap Tiles, and exchanged the web http access by a link within the local file system:

```
    var MyMapnikLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("myMapnik", "file:///D:/Tiles/myMapnik/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 16, alpha: true, isBaseLayer: true, visibility: false});
    map.addLayer(MyMapnikLayer);
```

Comment: thanks. but i get confused with how it displays the tiles since i used the generate_tiles.py and the output of the script is numerous folders categorized by their zoom levels

Comment: These folders are just the same structure as defined by D:/Tiles/myMapnik/${z}/${y}/. In my generate_tiles.py, I give this command :     try:  tile_dir = 'D:/Tiles/myMapnik/' (in two lines)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use [OpenLayers.Layer.TMS](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/TMS-js.html).